# JavaScript string initialization

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, from my understanding, the below are all same:

```
var carter2 = new String();
var carter2 = '';
var carter2 = "";
```

Which one is the most preferred?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't use

```
var str = new String();
```

Because

```
var str = new String("dog");
var str2 = new String("dog"); 
str == str2; // false
```

But

```
var str = "dog";
var str2 = "dog"; 
str == str2; // true
```

However, because of type coercion, the following works (Thanks to Rocket for pointing it out)

```
var str = new String("dog");
var str2 = "dog"; 
str == str2; // true
```

Single and double quotes don't matter, except for what quotes need to be escaped. <strike>Many others have noted that single quotes are better when creating HTML strings, since XHTML expects attributes to have double quotes, and you won't need to escape them.</strike>

Comment: Just a note: `new String('dog') == 'dog'` is true, but `new String('dog') === 'dog'` is false.  Note the `==` vs. `===`.

Comment: Another note: (X)HTML attributes can be quoted in either single or double quotes.

Answer (score 9):

When doing `new String()`, you are not being returned a `string` primitive, but a `String` object.

For all intents and purposes it acts like a `string` primitive, but there are cases where it won't.  For example:

```
var a = new String('body');
jQuery(a); // This will *not* function as expected
           // This will make a jQuery object containing a "String" object
           // It will NOT treat it as a selector string
```

Also when comparing things, there may be problem.  When you compare objects in JavaScript, it's only `true` if they are the *same exact object*, not just the same value.  Example:

```
var a = new String('test');
var b = new String('test');
var c = a;
var d = 'test';

a === b; // false, a and b are different objects (a == b is also false)
c === a; // true, a is the same object as c
c === b; // false, c (which is a) is a different object than b
d === a; // false, d is a primitive and a is an object, they are not equal
'test' === d; // true, they are both string primitives

d == a; // true, this uses "==" so only value is compared, not type
```

You can use `.valueOf()` to convert a `String` object to a `string` primitive.

```
new String('test').valueOf() === 'test'; // true
```

So, I *highly* suggest using `var a = ''` or `var a = ""`.  As for single quotes vs. double quotes, there is no difference.  Consider this example:

```
var a = "My name is Joe O'Ryan";
var b = 'My name is Joe O\'Ryan'; // need to escape the '
var c = 'Joe said: "Hi"';
var d = "Joe said \"HI\""; // need to escape the "
```

So, it's up to you whether to use `'` or `"`, but I suggest those over `new String()`.

Answer (score 2):

While `''` and `""` are the same (they are primitives), `new String()` is **not** because it returns a `String` *object*.

```
typeof '' == 'string'
typeof "" == 'string'
typeof new String() == 'object'
```

See [Distinction between string primitives and `String` objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Distinction_between_string_primitives_and_String_objects).

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use `var carter2 = '';` because:

1. It's not verbosive
2. Double quotes might clash with attributes double-quotes inside strings.

So I prefer to use single quotes in java-script, double quotes for html attributes.

UPD: this is my preference, I know that single-double quotes are interchangeable.

Comment: You can use single quotes in HTML attributes, `<a href='http://google.com'>Google</a>`.

Comment: I know I can. I was talking about my preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely without the constructor function call.

So with either single or double quotes (i.e. literal).

Note, this kind of optimization (literal vs. constructor) I believe would only matter if you had hundreds or thousands of these statements though.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "this would only matter if you had [many] statements" -- there's absolutely zero difference between `'` and `"`, but there's a [major difference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9946840/201952) between primitives and `String` objects.

Comment: uhh... that's what I was referring to.  I'm clearly favoring the literal vs. constructor (did you not read my answer?).  not arguing single vs. double.  I think you just misread, and definitely not worth two downvotes.

Comment: The problem is that there's a consideration much larger than just performance: the literals give you a string primitive, whereas the constructor gives you a `String` **object**.  See the other answers for the implications of that difference.

Comment: @thescientist You do point out that you should not use the String constructor, but you offer no valid reasons (just wild guesses) for it.